# Hive - how do I get only count of tables from a database as output

Tags: hive

how do I get 
- only count of tables from a database as output
- only count of columns from a table as output

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from the `metastore database`:

```
hive=> SELECT "TBL_NAME", "COLUMN_NAME", "TYPE_NAME" FROM "TBLS" , "COLUMNS_V2" WHERE "TBL_ID"="CD_ID" UNION SELECT "TBL_NAME", "PKEY_NAME", "PKEY_TYPE" FROM "PARTITION_KEYS" p , "TBLS" t WHERE p."TBL_ID"=t."TBL_ID" ORDER BY "TBL_NAME";

  TBL_NAME  | COLUMN_NAME | TYPE_NAME 
------------+-------------+-----------
 tableA     | aaa         | string
 tableA     | bbb         | string
 tableB     | foo         | string
 tableB     | bar         | int
 tableC     | cola        | string
 tableD     | colb        | string
(6 rows)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> select count(column_name) as NoOfColumns from information_schema.columns where table_name= "TableName";

hive> select count(table_name) as NoOfTables from information_schema.tables;
```

for more details: [click here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/using-hiveql/content/hive_query_information_schema.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sql("use {db}");
spark.sql("SHOW TABLES").count()
```